# CakePHP 2.* hooks execution only on selected controllers

Tags: php, cakephp

actually Am into CodeIgniter first time working on CakePHP.

I am using CakePHP 2.*. I want to call particular controller's method when user log in or when user tries to access other controller methods.

for e.g.

I have a controller `Licenses` in which I have method  `isSubscriptionvalid() {}` . This method will redirect user to "Buy Licenses" page if all subscriptions are expired.

How can I call method `isSubscriptionvalid()` written in controller `Licenses` without writing same code in each and every controller?

Comment: Add your common methods in AppController of CakePHP.

Comment: The redirect  $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'licenses', 'action' => 'buy'));  is not working from beforeFilter();  any suggestions..?

Comment: Have you added `public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}` in your child controller?

Comment: I have written $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'licenses', 'action' => 'buy'));  in appController's beforeFilter() { } method...

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND please update your question with some of the code. Otherwise it will be hard for people to help you.